# Can Flutter's PageView widget be implemented for a just selected section of the screen instead of the entire screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, swipe, flutter-pageview

Would it be possible to use the `PageView` widget just for the contents within `Expanded` widget in the code below? Essentially trying to swipe right for the items only within the `Expanded` widget instead of the entire screen.

```
class _MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(),
              Container(),
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(),
                      Container(),
                      ListView.builder(itemBuilder: itemBuilder),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

By doing this code below using the `PageView` widget, I get this error *'Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height'*.

```
class _MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(),
          Container(),
          PageView(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(),
                        Container(),
                        ListView.builder(itemBuilder: itemBuilder),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried doing that?

Comment: Yes I did. I get the error 'Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.' Do check out the code update.

Comment: wrap the pageview inside expanded. you are using expanded inside pageview

Comment: also wrap ListView.builder inside expanded too or inside sizedbox

Comment: Cheers mate. It works perfectly by just wrapping PageView inside Expanded. 
FYI, if I also wrap ListView.builder inside Expanded, the code breaks.

Comment: Great. I have answered the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the pageview inside expanded. you are using an expanded inside pageview

This should fix the issue